# Saving dictionary of header information using numpy.savez()

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, header

I am trying to save an array of data along with header information.  Currently, I am using numpy.savez() to save the header information (a dictionary) in one array, and the data in another.

```
    data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
    header = {'TIME': time, 'POSITION': position}
    np.savez(filename, header=header, data=data)
```

When I try to load and read the file, however, I can't index the header dictionary.

```
    arrays = np.load(filename)
    header = arrays('header')
    data = arrays('data')
    print header['TIME']
```

I get the following error:

```
    ValueError: field named TIME not found.
```

Before saving, the header is type 'dict'.  After saving/loading, it  is type 'numpy.ndarray'.  Can I convert it back to a dictionary?  Or is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: What are `time` and `position`?  If they are arrays, why don't you just save them directly: `np.savez(filename, data=data, TIME=time, POSITION=position)`

Comment: They are just numerical values.  My header dictionary has several parameters: sample rate, time duration, etc. I could use the approach you suggest, but I was hoping to send it all as a single dictionary.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`np.savez` saves only numpy arrays.  If you give it a dict, it will call `np.array(yourdict)` before saving it.  So this is why you see something like `type(arrays['header'])` as `np.ndarray`:

```
arrays = np.load(filename)
h = arrays['header'] # square brackets!!

>>> h
array({'POSITION': (23, 54), 'TIME': 23.5}, dtype=object)
```

You'll notice if you look at it though, that it is a 0-dimensional, single-item array, with one dict inside:

```
>>> h.shape
()
>>> h.dtype
dtype('O') # the 'object' dtype, since it's storing a dict, not numbers.
```

so you could work around by doing this:

```
h = arrays['header'][()]
```

The mysterious indexing gets the one value out of a 0d array:

```
>>> h
{'POSITION': (23, 54), 'TIME': 23.5}
```

Answer (score 5):

As in @askewchan's comment, why not `np.savez( "tmp.npz", data=data, **d )` ?

```
import numpy as np

data = np.arange( 3 )
time = 23.5
position = [[23, 54], None]
d = dict( TIME=time, POSITION=position )

np.savez( "tmp.npz", data=data, **d )

d = np.load( "tmp.npz" )
for key, val in sorted( d.items() ):
    print key, type(val), val  # note d.TIME is a 0-d array
```

---

This is not your question at all, but the following little `class Bag` is nice,
and you can `bag.<tab>` in IPython:

```
#...............................................................................
class Bag( dict ):
    """ a dict with d.key short for d["key"]
        d = Bag( k=v ... / **dict / dict.items() / [(k,v) ...] )  just like dict
    """
        # aka Dotdict

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        dict.__init__( self, *args, **kwargs )
        self.__dict__ = self

    def __getnewargs__(self):  # for cPickle.dump( d, file, protocol=-1)
        return tuple(self)


d = Bag( np.load( "tmp.npz" ))
if d.TIME > 0:
    print "time %g  position %s" % (d.TIME, d.POSITION)
```

Comment: I never knew that [()] trick to index zero dimensional arrays. Witchcraft!