# Change a saved value in an npz file

Tags: python, file

I saved "many" variables (about 40) into an npz file, all with names. From time to time I want to update one of these variables. Is there an easy way, how i can change one of the saved values in the npz file itself (not coping it into a dictionary, changing in the npz file, s.t the next time i load it it will be changed?)
Easy meaning I don't have to reenter all the variables with their corresponding variable names?

PS: This is not what I mean: [How do I change a value in a .npz file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891186/how-do-i-change-a-value-in-a-npz-file/37114439#37114439?newreg=1ac2206edd44438288c07a040d87606d) as it does not change the underlying npz file

Answer (score 0):

You can update arrays in npz file if you read it as a zip file:

```
import zipfile
from numpy.lib.format import write_array

zip_ = zipfile.ZipFile('archive.npz', 'a')
with zip_.open('array.npy', 'w', force_zip64=True) as fid:
    write_array(fid, np.asanyarray(v))
zip_.close()
```

Logic for updating an array is copied from [savez](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/b235f9e701e14ed6f6f6dcba885f7986a833743f/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L721)